# How to send bundle from baseAdapter to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-adapter, baseadapter

Actually i am sending bundle from my base adapter to a new fragment. how I send bundle from adapter to frament.
here is my adapter code:

```
 textViewItemName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ExpandableCategoryList fragment = new ExpandableCategoryList();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putInt("Id",Id);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                ((MainActivity)context).replaceFragment(fragment,
                        "TAG",null,false);
                //Log.e("Hello",fragment.toString());
            }
        });
```

and i am receiving mu bundle as

```
int id = getArguments().getInt("Id",0);
```

but i am getting that getArguments().getInt() throws null point exception. How I handle it

Answer (score 3):

In your Adapter, write the code

```
ExpandableCategoryList fragmentProductLaptop = new ExpandableCategoryList();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=context.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("Name",category.getCategoryName());
args.putInt("Id",category.getId());
fragmentProductLaptop.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id. homeFrameLayout, fragmentProductLaptop);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In your Fragment Class, write the below code :

```
    public class ExpandableCategoryList extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String name = getArguments().getString("Name"); 
        String Id = getArguments().getInt("Id",0); 
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer my Answer from the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/41075878/5715935

Comment: what is the Error? can you explain?

Comment: yes. I am getting error that
AppCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference

Comment: can you paste the whole adapter as well as activity class where you getting error?

Comment: try to pass any other value in your baseAdapter like,                             
args.putInt("Id",10);                                                                                                       to check that your category.getId() is not null.